# Convert placed on Embedded attribute must define (sub)attributeName

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

I have an entity *VendorProductMapping*. It consists an embedded primary key *VendorProductMappingPk*. To convert the embedded primary key to string and vice-versa, I followed [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters) link. I'm seeing an error saying

> Convert placed on Embedded attribute must define (sub)attributeName

VendorProductMapping.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vendor_product")
public class VendorProductMapping {

    @EmbeddedId
    @Convert(converter = VendorProductMappingIdConverter.class)
    private VendorProductMappingPk id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("vendorId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id")
    private Vendor vendor;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("productId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    //getters setters etc
}
```

VendorProductMappingPk.java:

```
@Embeddable
public class VendorProductMappingPk implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "vendor_id")
    private int vendorId;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int productId;

    public VendorProductMappingPk() {

    }

    public VendorProductMappingPk(int vendorId, int productId) {
        this.vendorId = vendorId;
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    //getters, setters, equals and hascode methods
}
```

VendorProductMappingIdConverter.java

```
@Converter
public class VendorProductMappingIdConverter implements AttributeConverter<VendorProductMappingPk, String> {

    private static final String SEPARATOR = ", ";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(VendorProductMappingPk vendorProductMappingPk) {
        //logic for conversion to string
    }

    @Override
    public VendorProductMappingPk convertToEntityAttribute(String dbPersonName) {
        //logic for conversion to MyEmbeddedPrimaryKeyClass
    }
}
```

How to use converter with EmbeddedId ?

Comment: Why would you need a converter for that? It is default JPA support that already does this. Ditch the annotation and the converter

Comment: @M.Deinum but it is not working. It says "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.UI.entity.VendorProductMappingPk'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.UI.entity.VendorProductMappingPk': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"

Comment: Why would it need to convert to a string? It as a primary key consisting of 2 different fields. So why on earth should JPA convert that to a single string?

Comment: If I want to send that primary key as a @RequestParam ?

Comment: Then you need a Spring converter **not** a JPA converter. You are mixing up 2 different things.